# How do I configure Ubuntu one on a server?

Tags: server, ubuntu-one

I wish to setup Ubuntu One on my 11.10 server but seems to be running into an error every time I attempt to run commands from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/u1sdtool.1.html

For example when I try to run  `u1sdtool --start` I am met with the following error:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

I have just installed Ubuntu One and have made no changes to it thus far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu One requires X and a dbus session. You can make it work headless following these instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Headless

Running Ubuntu One in Headless Mode

1. Install ubuntuone-client package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client
   ```
2. Setup the user directories:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.config/ubuntuone ~/bin
   ```

   If you did not have a ~/bin when you logged in, your path doesn't include it, to rectify run (or simply log out and in again and ubuntu will set it up for you):

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Obtain OAuth key for your account:

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/ubuntuone-sso-login.py
   python ubuntuone-sso-login.py
   Ubuntu SSO Login: **your Ubuntu SSO Login**
   Password: **your Ubuntu SSO Password**
   oauth=hPQWPsH:rhOokmNiRuuoiHe...
   ```
4. Copy the line starting with oauth= to ~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf as oauth parameter under **main** section (this is ini-style file):

   ```
   [__main__]
   oauth=hPQWPsH:rhOokmNiRuuoiHe...
   ```

   (you might just as well remove the first two fields in the oauth-string, ie oath=aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd => oath=ccc:ddd )
5. Download the u1sdtool wrapper which will start dbus when needed. By default Ubuntu adds ~/bin/ to your path, so when you run u1sdtool, you will be running the wrapper.

   ```
   wget http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/u1sdtool-wrapper -O ~/bin/u1sdtool
   chmod +x ~/bin/u1sdtool
   ```
6. Start Ubuntu One, check Ubuntu One status and connect (starting from Oneiric Ubuntu One is connecting automatically when started):

   ```
   u1sdtool --start
   u1sdtool --status
   State: READY
     connection: Not User With Network
     description: ready to connect
     is_connected: False
     is_error: False
     is_online: False
     queues: IDLE
   u1sdtool --connect
   ```

   If you are greeted with a with the display manager error, try prepending u1sdtool with ~/bin/ since the most probable cause are the aforementioned issue with your PATH.
7. Look at the string followed by "connection". If it says "Not User" your credentials haven't been processed, stop and start the syncdaemon:

   ```
   u1sdtool --quit
   u1sdtool --start
   ```

   and try again.

   If it says "No network", it claims you're not connected to the internet, and I had to fix this by installing nmcli (sudo apt-get install network-manager --no-install-recommends) and fiddle with nmcli. You might need to install consolekit, too.
8. Start adding files to `~/Ubuntu One` directory and u1sdtool to add UDF, publish the files etc.

Comment: If possible do not use links but copy the content over :)

Comment: The part that gets me is step 4. as my syncdaemon.conf looks like this:       

[notifications]
show_all_notifications = True

[bandwidth_throttling]
on = True
read_limit = 2097152
write_limit = 102400[notifications]
show_all_notifications = True 

    Now when I add step 4 to the file at the top, I am still met with the display manager issue.

Comment: I wish this worked for me, but I'm getting 'With User Not Network' and I have no idea what you mean by 'fiddle with nmcli'.  I already have network-manager and my internet connection is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue.

Turns out it was because I was connecting with screen+ssh.

http://www.rootninja.com/dbus-session-bus-address-with-applications-using-ssh/

Running this solves the issue for me:

```
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
```

Comment: Ideally, you'd stick that in your login file (.profile, .bash_login, .bash_profile, .zshrc, whatever) and wrap it in an "if [[ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ]]" block. :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ubuntuone-syncdaemon will only work with managed interfaces, so you need to make sure that NetworkManager is running and at least one managed network is connected.

```
$ sudo nmctl con
```

If your server, like mine, has a static IP address configured, you need to modify `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` as described here:  http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Enabling_Interface_Management