# Installing Ubuntu One on Ubuntu 11.10 server

Tags: ubuntu-one, python, gtk, pygtk

I have installed "Ubuntu One" on an Ubuntu server 11.10 based on these instructions:

- [How do I configure Ubuntu one on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95591/how-do-i-configure-ubuntu-one-on-a-11-10)

Everything went smooth during installation. However when I try the command: `u1sdtool --start` to get the server up, I get the following stack error:

```
u1sdtool --start /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/init.py:57: 
GtkWarning: could not open display warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning) 
Unhandled Error Traceback (most recent call last): 
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: 
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read point 5 in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Headless which is linked in the answer on that question.

Comment: I did run the commands from point #5 but I still get the above error...

Comment: What does "which u1sdtool" say?

Comment: /usr/bin/u1sdtool

Comment: Then you have either not done the tasks listed in point #5 (if you did download the file, it's not named u1sdtool, or possibly not flagged as executable), or ~/bin is not in your $PATH.