# Can I run Ubuntu One in a Ubuntu Server environment?

Tags: 12.04, installation, ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure Ubuntu one on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95591/how-do-i-configure-ubuntu-one-on-a-server)

Can I run Ubuntu One client (sync up whatever in my 'Ubuntu One' folder), in an Ubuntu Server environment?

If yes, how can I install Ubuntu One client in my server environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You can find in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/95967/38150) answer how to do this: